# Symfony2 - OneToMany empty ArrayCollection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities: `Review` and `User`. There is a user's OneToMany relationship in `User` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Review", mappedBy="owner")
 */
 protected $reviews;

 public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();

   $this->reviews = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
 }
```

And connection in `Review` entity looks like below:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="reviews")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $owner;
```

In a controller, I am trying to get all the reviews for logged user. So I am using a `getReviews()` getter generated from console.

```
/**
 * @Route("/dashboard")
 */
 public function dashboardShow() {
   $user = new User();
   $reviews = $user->getReviews();

   return $this->render('dashboard.html.twig', array(
     'reviews' => $reviews
   ));
 }
```

But `$reviews` seems empty, when i dump it, I get: `object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)#285 (1) { ["elements":"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":private]=> array(0) { } }`

Tables in database are populated. Could any one of you point me what I'm missing?

Comment: You make a new User entity which will be empty of course. You should load the User from the database or add the reviews with a method like $user->addReview($review); . If you want to see ALL reviews than you do not need a releationship.

Comment: @Frankbeen, thanks for the response! I wanted to get reviews only for the user (reviews with `owner_id` = currently logged user ID). I have managed to workaround by manually creating a query with doctrine's Querybuilder - I thought that getter was a better way to obtain that data, but it seems that query builder works too.

Comment: if you want to have the currently logged-in user then you could simply use the $user = $this->getUser() method in the controller. Or in your situation: $reviews = $this->getUser()->getReviews();

Comment: Alright! One more question just to clear up: When I want to do something like SELECTing records from one table JOINing another with "WHERE a.id = b.something" clause, I have to use query builder, not Entity's getter, correct? Sorry for those newbie questions.

Comment: OK, I just learned about Repositories and querying them (`find` and similar ones). If you want to write a short answer and mention that I have mixed up getters with SELECT querying, I'll be happy to select this as a correct answer. Thank you for helping me clarify this!

Comment: correct. getters and setter you will use after an entity has been loaded (or created). You write select queries to get loaded what you want

Answer (score 2):

yes it's empty, because collection is not initialized (in dump there is also "#initialized: false")

how to initialize a collection? there are more ways how to do it:

call

```
$user->getReviews()->count()
```

or make custom SQL function in the repository

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('user')
->select('user, reviews')
->leftJoin('user.review', 'reviews')
->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first retrieve the logged in user and then load their related entity.

```
/**
 * @Route("/dashboard")
 */
public function dashboardShow() {
    // Pulls the currently authenticated user from symfony internals
    $user = $this->getUser(); 
    // If your authentication provider already pulls this entity from the database
    // you can skip this step and just use $user->getReviews(); below.
    $userEntity = $this->get('doctrine')
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('NamespacedBundle:User')
        ->findOne($user->getId());

    $reviews = $userEntity->getReviews();

    return $this->render('dashboard.html.twig', array(
        'reviews' => $reviews
    ));
}
```